# Dragging a shape in Photoshop doesn't show outline

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop

I've created a shape in Photoshop with the Rounded Rectangle tool. Now I want to reposition it. When I use the Path Selection tool to move it, Photoshop doesn't seem to pick up the shape. When I let go of the mouse button, the shape moves to wherever I've moved the mouse. I'm used to there being an outline as I drag, so I can position the shape in its final place but this outline isn't showing up.

Is there some setting like "Show outline when dragging" that I've changed by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem wasn't with a setting, but something to do with the OS itself. I logged out and in again and my outlines were back.

Just in case anyone else has this problem, I'm running Mac OS 10.6.3 on a Macbook Pro.